# unable to retrieve selected array values [php]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

**To generate the stockroom drop down list**

```
function einv_generateStockrmSelectDropdown($Stockrm,$field,$dropdown) {
    //connect to database
    base_connectDatabase();
    echo "<select id=\"stockrm\" name=\"".$field."[]\" multiple=\"multiple\" style=\"align:left\" class=\"form-control\">";

    if (isset($Stockrm) && ($Stockrm != "")) {
        $stockrmname = einv_getStockrmDetail($Stockrm);
        echo "<option value=\"". $Stockrm ."\">". $stockrmname['einv_stockrm_name'] ."</option>";
    } else {
        $Stockrm = 0;
    }
    $getStockrmSQL = base_executeSQL("SELECT * FROM einv_stockroom WHERE einv_stockrm_id<>" . $Stockrm . " ORDER BY einv_stockrm_name");
    while ($Stockrmdata_row = base_fetch_array($getStockrmSQL)) {
       if (base_num_rows($getStockrmSQL)!= 0) {
           echo "<option value=\"".$Stockrmdata_row['einv_stockrm_id']."\">".$Stockrmdata_row['einv_stockrm_name']."</option>";
       }
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<script src=\"../terms_base/js/jquery.multiple.select.js\">     </script>";

    //Input some codes to split the dropdown and make it into the setSelects. By default, the first time = AutoSelectAll
    if(isset($dropdown) && ($dropdown != "")) { //dropdown = 1;2;3
        $SDDArrays = explode(";", $dropdown);
        $countTrap0 = count($SDDArrays);
        $drop = "$('#stockrm').multipleSelect(\"setSelects\", [";
        $counting = 1;
        foreach ($SDDArrays as &$value) {
            if ($countTrap0 != $counting) {
                $drop .= "'". $value . "',";
            } else {
                $drop .= "'". $value . "'";
            }
            $counting++;
        }
        $drop .= "]);\n";
    } elseif (isset($dropdown)) { //dropdown=
        $drop = "$('#stockrm').multipleSelect(\"uncheckAll\")";
    } else { //
        $drop = "$('#stockrm').multipleSelect(\"checkAll\")";
    }

    echo "<script>\n";
    echo "$(function() {\n";
    echo "".$drop."";
    echo "});\n";
    echo "$(\"#stockrm\").multipleSelect({ onClose: function() {
            document.getElementById('search').click();
        }});\n";
    echo "$(\"#stockrm\").multipleSelect();\n";
    echo "</script>";

    //close the database
    base_closeDatabase();
}


//This function is use to add new stock room
//code = stock room code
//name = stock room name
//desc = stock room description
//remark = stock room remark
//cat = stock room category
```

**add stockroom function**

```
function einv_addStockrm($code,$name,$desc,$remark,$cat)
{
    //connect to database
    base_connectDatabase();
    $User = base_getUserDetail($_SESSION['uID']);

base_executeSQL("INSERT INTO einv_stockroom (einv_stockrm_code, einv_stockrm_name, einv_stockrm_desc, einv_stockrm_remark, einv_stockrm_cat)
VALUES ('" . $code . "', '" . $name . "', '" . $desc . "', '" . $remark . "', '" . $cat . "')");

base_addTransactionLog('Manage Stock Room', 'Add',
"
Stock Room Code = " . $code . " ||
Stock Room Name = " . $name . " ||
Stock Room Description = " . $desc . " ||
Stock Room Remark = " . $remark . " ||
Stock Room Category = " . $cat . "
");
        //go to stock room page
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">' . "\n";
        echo 'window.location="../einventory/stockrm_list.php";';
        echo '</script>';
    //close the database
    base_closeDatabase();
}
```

**Edit stockroom**

```
function einv_editStockrm($srid,$code,$name,$desc,$remark,$cat)
{
    //connect to database
    base_connectDatabase();

    $User = base_getUserDetail($_SESSION['uID']);
    $Stockroom = einv_getStockrmDetail($srid);
    base_executeSQL("UPDATE einv_stockroom
    SET einv_stockrm_code='" . $code . "',
    einv_stockrm_name='" . $name . "',
    einv_stockrm_desc='" . $desc . "',
    einv_stockrm_remark='" . $remark . "',
    einv_stockrm_cat = '" . $cat . "'
    WHERE einv_stockrm_id=" . $srid . "");

    base_addTransactionLog('Manage Stock Room', 'Edit',
    "
    Stock Room Code = " . $code . " ||
    Stock Room Name = " . $name . " ||
    Stock Room Description = " . $desc . " ||
    Stock Room Remark = " . $remark . " ||
    Stock Room Category = " . $cat . "
    ");
        //go to stock room page
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">' . "\n";
        echo 'window.location="../einventory/view_stockrm.php?id='. $srid .'";';
        echo '</script>';



    //close the database
    base_closeDatabase();
}
```

File name: add_Stockroom.php and edit_stockroom.php

I have a dropdown list named **Stockroom** where it displays an array of values.

Example:

**Stockroom**

1. [A]
2. [B]
3. [C]

When user clicks on [A], it will display relevant data fields that [A] possess (appears below stockroom ddl).

And as user clicks on [B], there is an onchange function that will then show [B] data fields (fields in A is deleted and replaced with B).

I am able to add the initial values however, as i want to edit and change the stockroom from [A] to [B] which will result in a whole new data to be stored, i am unable to do so.

Any ideas?

I believe i have to amend my edit stockroom function where i require a set of coding such as

If the array is selected, i have to delete existing data and add new data in accordance to the selected ID.

Comment: Try creating a minimum, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with a narrowly targeted question. Asking people to wade through this much code makes it harder to get quality responses, and doesn't serve future users of the site as well.